# How to access member variables, from non member function within class C++

Tags: c++

I have created a class called "ShortestTime".  I have some functions within it that are not member functions, but I would like them to be able to access my member variables.
ie. I have a function that sorts a List that is a public member variable, but it doesn't have access to this member variable.

I have read something about "friend" but was unable to get this to work.  How do I solve my problem?

Thanks for the help,

Robin

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: Your Question is not obvious, maybe you mean that the fuction is outside the class and you want it to gain access to the class fields. But if the field is public (such as the list you talked about), then any fuction can reach it!. Please clarify your question. Also Friendship is a relationship that gives non-member functions or classes access to private and protected members...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways you could use friend to solve your problem but we would need to see sample code.

But my personal approach would be to add a function to ShortestTime that sorts your private member.

```
ShortestTime::SortInterals()
{
   //sort private stuff
}
```

Is there a reason that won't work?

Comment: Ya, that would work.  I think I've just been working for too long, not thinking clearly because that is definitely what I should have done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on what language we are talking about here. Since you are talking about "friend" functions, I am going to assume you are talking about c++. 
So basically, a friend function is just a normal function which has access to private and protected members of a class in c++. For example..

```
int abc(myclass a)    
{   
...   
}   
class myclass   
{   
    int someprivatemembers;   
    public:   
        function myClass() { ... }   
        friend int abc(myclass);   
}
```

Now, in the above example, the function abc will have access to someprivatemembers of object a passes to it, because it is declared as a "friend" of the class.

Comment: Put four spaces in front of code to get the correct formatting.

Comment: @Martin oh thanks! I was struggling with the formatting. Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a class called "ShortestTime". I have some functions within it that are not member functions, ...

No you don't :-).  All the functions within a class are member functions by definition.  You might well have some functions with*out* the class - they would not be member functions.

> but I would like them to be able to access my member variables.
>   ie. I have a function that sorts a List that is a public member variable, but it doesn't have access to this member variable.

Yes it does.  You've said you have a public member variable List:

```
class X
{
  public:
    List identifier_;
};
```

All functions have access to the list, irrespective of whether they're member functions or not.

> I have read something about "friend" but was unable to get this to work. How do I solve my problem?

The only situation in which you might find you need friend, and hence the one that might apply despite the statements above, is akin to...

```
class X
{
  public:

  private:
    List identifier_;
};

void some_non_member_function()
{
    X x;
    x.identifier_;  // HOW TO GET ACCESS...?
}
```

To grant some_non_member_function() access to a private data member, you can...

**make it a `friend` of the class**

```
class X
{
    friend void some_non_member_function();
};

void some_non_member_function()
{
    X x;
    x.identifier_;  // NOW OK
}
```

**make it a member function**

```
class X
{
  public:
    void some_non_member_function()
    {
        X x;
        x.identifier_;  // NOW OK
    }
};
```

Comment: k, I probably should clarify what I did.  I created a class with a header and .c file.  In the .c file, I created a function that was not declared in the header file and was not within the class(which I assume to mean its not a member function, correct me if I'm wrong). My initial question was that I was having problems getting this function to be able to access the member variables of the class member function it was being used in. It was simply a void function I used to update some member Lists, but I made it a member function since I couldnt see any reason not to and that was that.

Comment: @Robin: yes, sounds sensible... functions that need access to (non-public) member variables are typically best being member functions.  All good.